# Securing login form in a desktop app

Tags: c#, authentication

I currently have a desktop application which requires the user to have a username and a password. These credentials are stored on a webserver (myserver.com), so when he types the username and the password and clicks on the Login button, they're sent to the webserver.
If the credentials are right, the server will return "ok" and the main form will be displayed. If not, the server will return "wrong" and an alert will be displayed.
However, this is very insecure, because a user can just edit the hosts file, redirect myserver.com to his localhost, which always returns "ok", and bypass the login screen.

How can I make a more secure login form for a desktop app?

Comment: You can make the server return something more meaningful than "ok", like an encrypted session key - then decrypt it in your application and find out whether it is valid. The decrypted key should include a timestamp, in order to determine whether that key has timed-out as a valid key. This is far from secured, but it is one step closer. Most of the people who know to change the hosts file, don't know to look into your code and extract the decryption and validation logic to generate valid server results.

Comment: is this an application that's in your Domain / Work Network.. what about using Active Directory along with SQL Server , or you can use encryption for sure.. hostfile... I would change that to utilize a .config file and even then you can encrypt that as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way off the top of my head to validate if the answer is coming from the "trusted" server is by generating a public/private RSA key pair and include the public key in the application and keep the private key on the server.  Then, when you connect to the server, you can do some rudimentary server authentication by having the client send a random number/string ("nonce") to the server encrypted with the server's public key and see if the server can send it back unencrypted (decrypting with its private key).  Since only the server should have this private key, if it is sent back unencrypted, you can be sure it came from the "trusted" server.  Afterwards, you can authenticate your user.

However, if you're really trying to secure this application, there are some issues you should address overall - such as the fact that you're sending the username and password to the server as plain text. Perhaps use SSL instead and my previous suggestion becomes moot.  Next, is the information you're trying to secure within the application binaries itself?  If so, simple reflection may expose the data to the user anyway.  If the data you're trying to secure is external, then you would need to make sure that the data source you're pulling it from can trust that the client's request is authorized.

Comment: The webserver is actually in Heroku, so I can use https. Is it worth adding that RSA nonce?

Comment: You would need your server to require a client certificate which you would have to bundle with the client application which would confirm for the server that the request is coming from your application.  However, if you bundle it with your application, then a devious user could extract it and use it to make whatever calls he wants.  Are the users and servers on the same or trusted domain so that you could use integrated Windows Authentication instead of having them enter a username and password?